# GeoServer tiling gridset problem

Tags: geoserver

I'm experiencing an issue with a WMTS service created in GeoServer. I've created a new gridset in EPSG:5514 and subsequently published the WMTS service using this gridset.
[image: Gridset detail]

However, when I open the preview window in GeoServer and adjust the map scale, the data in the WMTS service shifts position and appears duplicated (see picture bellow).

[image]

Additionally, there are problems with this WMTS service in ArcGIS Pro and ArcMap - the service fails to load. However, when I open the service in QGIS, it functions without any issues.

I also attempted to publish this service in default gridset EPSG:4326, and it works without problems across GeoServer, QGIS, ArcMap, and ArcGIS Pro. However, when I created a copy of this gridset and adjusted the scales of the gridset, the same issue arose: the data in the WMTS service shifted position and appeared duplicated.

Comment: please add some details about your gridset

Comment: I don't think a gridset that isn't even powers of two (i.e, doubling/halving) each step will work, the maths is more difficult so it's possible the ESRI and OpenLayers can't be bothered to do the maths while QGIS does?

Comment: I also tried a grid with "doubled" scales, but it didn't help.